# Count all possible word combinations from two arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I want to display the total number of possible unique word combinations.

This is my sample code:

```
var wordlist1 = ["Goldener", "Stählerner", "Purpurner", "Strahlender", "Elektrischer", "Taumelnder"];       
var wordlist2 = ["Indianer", "Ast", "Dachs", "Wolfshund", "Schäferhund", "Lupus", "Schakal"] ;
```

How can I achieve this with JS or Jquery?

Comment: (n*p).... (if order doesnt matter so /2)

Comment: How is this specific to javascript?

Comment: Do single words count? Does order matter? Is `Purpurner Ast` and `Ast Purpurner` count as one or two? Do you only want two-word combos or should it go to the full set where all words from both arrays would be one of the combos?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934372/jquery-array-concatenation-of-specific-combinations-except-where-duplicate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058868/finding-all-possible-value-combinations-between-two-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of combinations is wordlist1.length * wordlist2.length

To display the combinations:

```
for (i = 0; i < wordlist1.length; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < wordlist2.length; j++){
    // do something like alert(wordlist1[i] + " " + wordlist2[j]);
    // or append the combinations somewhere
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Example for ONE list... put the for-loop in a function and you've got it :-)

```
var wordlist1 = ["Goldener", "Stählerner", "Purpurner", "Strahlender", "Elektrischer", "Taumelnder"];
var wordlist2 = ["Indianer", "Ast", "Dachs", "Wolfshund", "Schäferhund", "Lupus", "Schakal"];

var uniqueWords = [];

for (var i = 0; i < wordlist1.length; i++) {
    var isUnique = true;

    for (var j = 0; j < uniqueWords.length; j++) { 
        if (wordlist1[i] == uniqueWords[j]) {
          isUnique = false;
          break;
        }
    }

    if (isUnique)
        uniqueWords.push(wordlist1[i]);
}

alert(uniqueWords.join("|"));
```

Comment: Thanks all. It worked an I've learned something. Sorry if my questions are too basic for some users here. I have very limited time and I really appreciate your answers to even very basic things. I still have to get to a level where I can think of a quick solution myself.

Comment: That's no problem. We all started from level 0 :-)