# Simple two digits permutation value check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a basic "lockbreaker". A user has 100 "passcodes" (total number of possibilities) to go through and the loop will go through all of them one by one, put the value in the Input field, and click the button (NOTE: All this is done by the JS, not user). On clicking the button the value is checked by another function named "check()". The function check has the variable xyz which has the passcode as 18. If the value submitted in the input field is equal to 18, it displays "Yes" in    p element named as "para".

Then the loop is checking if p has an text of "Yes" in it. If it has so, then it will terminate then and there and alert the user the code is **i**. If it doesn't match continue the loop till 100 (the last possibility). Here is what I have tried so far. Apologies, but I was out of touch with JS quite a few months, and was more focused on Java and Python.

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script>
function check(){
var xyz = 18;
var val = document.getElementById("text").value;
if (xyz == val) {
document.getElementById("para").innerHTML="yes";
}
}
</script>
<script>
var char = 2;
no = 10;
possible = (no^char);
 for (var i = 1; i <=possible; i++) {
var c = i;
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = i;
  $("bttn").click;
  var textinp = document.getElementById("para").value;
  if (textinp == i.toString()) {
   alert("Code is"+i);
 break;
 }
 }
</script>
<input id = "text">
<button id="bttn" onClick="check()">Click</button>
<p id = "para"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: `(no^char)` that isn't JavaScript.

Comment: What do you want to do with this '$("bttn").click;'? Execute the onClick function? If yes, you must change to this '$("#bttn").click();'

Comment: It will permute all possible combinations and check i against xyz for all possible numbers. When i = xyz (18), alert user "Code is " + i. That's it. The JS is automatically putting in i every time the loop runs in the input box and is clicking the button, the button checks if i = 18, if so, check() writes "Yes" in p element. If "Yes" exists then terminate loop and print i value (alert).

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery array concatenation of specific combinations except where duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934372/jquery-array-concatenation-of-specific-combinations-except-where-duplicate)